# How does VBA ByRef work behind the scenes?

Tags: vba

Let's say I have a function that takes an Integer value ByRef, like this:

```
Function myFunc(ByRef funcVal As Integer)
  funcVal = funcVal + 1
End Function
```

And let's suppose I call it like this:

```
Dim myVal as Integer
myVal = 5
Call myFunc(myVal)
```

As I understand it, the computer has allocated space for my `myVal` variable and put the value 5 in that space. When I call `myFunc`, the computer basically passes a pointer to that location to `myFunc`, so that when `myFunc` increments `funcVal`, it is actually incrementing the same location, so `myVal` is also incremented.

But what happens if instead I call myFunc like this:

```
Call myFunc(5)
```

Does the computer still give `myFunc` a pointer, and if so a pointer to what? Or does it have to assign some fresh space to `funcVal` (instead of just using the same space as `myVal` like it did in my previous example)?

I suppose there's also a related question here - how does VBA handle literal values in the code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables are stored at memory addresses. So are literals. So are procedures. AND SO ARE PROCEDURE PARAMETERS.

Parameters are locally scoped variables and they are distinct and separate entities from arguments passed to the procedure. The [VB ***virtual machine***](https://www.file.net/process/msvbvm60.dll.html) manages all these entity addresses in a table.

When a variable argument is passed by reference a pointer is passed to the associated procedure parameter and this gives the parameter direct memory access to the calling variable address.

HOWEVER, literals themselves are obviously immutable, so when a literal argument is passed by reference, the VM is forced to make a copy of the literal to a temporary address and this new address is passed by reference to the procedure. This allows the procedure to use AND UPDATE the value during execution without affecting the original literal value outside of the procedure.

> In essence literals are always passed by value and passing by value
> actually means passing a pointer to a copy of the calling argument.

Comment: Ah - fascinating and excellent answer - thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: If you optimize the program so that there is always a 5 at the same location, and the compiler fails to mark the location as immutable, the function can change the value of (5) to be 4.  In the 1960's, it was a feature of the small, simple, fast compilers that used this kind of optimization.